# Shell script to delete files smaller than x kb

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, scripting

I'm trying to find out how to write a little script to delete text files that are smaller than 50 Kilobytes but I have had no success.

My attempt looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt
do
   if [ stat -c %s < 5 ]
   then
     rm $i
   fi
done
```

I would appriciate some guidance, thank you!

Comment: note your `if` statement does not contain the closing `fi`.

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use fedorqui's version, but for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ./*.txt   # ./ avoids some edge cases when files start with dashes
do
  # $(..) can be used to get the output of a command
  # use -le, not <, for comparing numbers
  # 5 != 50k
  if [ "$(stat -c %s "$i")" -le 50000 ]
  then
    rm "$i"  # specify the file to delete      
  fi # end the if statement
done
```

It's usually easier to write a program piece by piece and verifying that each part works, rather than writing the entire program and then trying to debug it.

Answer (score 13):

You can directly use `find` with the `size` option for this:

```
find /your/path -name "*.txt" -size -50k -delete
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
                              if you wanted bigger than 50k, you'd say +50
```

You may want to stick to the files in the current directory, without going down in the directory structure. If so, you can say:

```
find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -size -50k -delete
```

---

From [`man find`](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html):

> -size n[cwbkMG]
>
> File uses n units of space. The following suffixes can be used:
>
> 'b' for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>
> 'c' for bytes
>
> 'w' for two-byte words
>
> 'k' for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
>
> 'M' for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
>
> 'G' for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)